Why doesn't my Docker image build as expected given my Dockerfile?
# Use an official Ubuntu as the base image\
ARG BASE_IMAGE=eclipse-temurin:8-jdk
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

# Set environment variable for non-interactive apt installs
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install necessary dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    curl \
    unzip \
    sudo \
    screen \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /tekkit2

# Download Tekkit 2 Server (make sure to replace URL with the official one)
RUN wget -O Tekkit2.zip https://servers.technicpack.net/Technic/servers/tekkit-2/Tekkit-2_Server_v1.2.4.zip \
    && unzip Tekkit2.zip \
    && rm Tekkit2.zip

RUN echo "#!/bin/bash\njava -server -Xmx5G -Dfml.queryResult=confirm -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar nogui" > Server.sh \
    && chmod 755 Server.sh

# Accept Minecraft EULA (skip this if you want to manually accept the EULA)
# RUN echo "eula=true" > eula.txt

# Expose the Minecraft default port
EXPOSE 25565

ENTRYPOINT [ "./Server.sh" ]`

Using this Dockerfile I'm unable to get the ENTRYPOINT to execute properly. When I try to run a container using this image, I get:
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./Server.sh": stat ./Server.sh: no such file or directory: unknown

I can run it successfully by creating the container with:
docker run -it --entrypoint ./Server.sh tekkit2-server

Why would this command work and not the ENTRYPOINT? I've inspected the Docker image's files and Server.sh is in the proper directory. I must be missing some aspect of how Docker functions. There is a file called LaunchServer.sh that is unzipped as part of the Tekkit2.zip file and I was unable to overwrite its contents using the echo command so I opted to create a new shell script instead. This seems odd to me as well, considering the echo "eula=true" > eula.txt works just fine.
I've tried overwriting the LaunchServer.sh script with:
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash\njava -server -Xmx5G -Dfml.queryResult=confirm -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar nogui" > LaunchServer.sh

This didn't work so I instead tried creating a new shell script called Server.sh. However it looks like when I start the container it can't find that Server.sh file despite it being in the WORKDIR.

Why do you need a bash shell script to run a single command?

You script contains one line witht he content:
#!/bin/bash\njava -server -Xmx5G -Dfml.queryResult=confirm -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar nogui

There is no such file or directory as /bin/bash\njava.

Why doesn't my Docker image build as expected given my Dockerfile?

Because you expect \n to be a newline inside " quotes, while it is not.
Consider:
RUN printf "%s\n" \
     "#!/bin/bash" \
     "java -server -Xmx5G -Dfml.queryResult=confirm -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar nogui" \
     > LaunchServer.sh


(and the -e flag to echo turns on escape interpretation)

I had previously tried implementing it with the -e flag, but the echo command never seemed to actually execute. For reference my previous implementation was: RUN echo -e "#!/bin/bash\njava -server -Xmx5G -Dfml.queryResult=confirm -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar nogui" > Server.sh

Unfortunately, RUN printf "%s\n" \      "#!/bin/bash" \      "java -server -Xmx5G -Dfml.queryResult=confirm -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar nogui" \      > LaunchServer.sh does not function properly. The LaunchServer.sh script still contains is original contents and has not been overwritten.
